# Web service not returning json data

Tags: json, web-services

I am trying to return json data to use it before I start my metro UI app.
My web service doesnt return json data but it always retunr xml data. Could some on ehelp me on this.

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] 
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

HTML Page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" > 
<head> 
    <title>Untitled Page</title> 
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); 

        function Roll() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                alert(req.responseText);
                alert("exiting");
            }
        }

        function Test() {
            alert("starting");
            req.open("POST", "http://localhost:58718/testService/Service.asmx/HelloWorld", true);
            req.onreadystatechange = Roll;
            req.send(null);
        } 


    </script> 
</head> 
<body> 

    <button onclick="javascript:Test()">TEST</button> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your web configuration file.

```
<httpHandlers>
<remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
<add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory" validate="false"/>
</httpHandlers>
```

Faith Sloan

Comment: These line are there by default in my web.config file. I am using framework version 3.5.